# Media is shown in listview but not in gridview whenever i activate my Custom Theme

Tags: media

Whenever I activate my custom theme the media is shown in list view only not in grid view. When I checked it by inspect element data is not coming in it and when i try to upload any image it shows me this error, but the image is uploaded in the wp-content/uploads folder then why this error is shown?

List View :
[image: List View]

Grid View :
[image]

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: So I want to ask why media is not showing in the grid view ?

Comment: how do you expect anyone to even guess with the amount of details you have given?

Comment: I am unaware of the reason why it is happening thats why details are less. I have added the screenshot of the list and grid view.

Comment: have you checked for JS errors?

Comment: There is no error of JS in console.

Comment: in that case you will have to post much more of your code. But it is almost impossible to help you debug things, you will just need to remove pieces of your code until you find the one that causes it, then you can post it and ask about it (if it will not be obvious why it creates the problem)

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you suggested i started removing pieces of code and found error in my function.php file.